# How to set accessibilityIdentifier to UICollectionViewListCell accessory?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewlistcell

I need to expand/collapse my cell in my tests automation which relies on `accessibilityIdentifier` field in `UIView`s.

This is how I set my accessory to the cell:

```swift
func headerCellRegistartion(
) -> UICollectionView.CellRegistration<MyCollectionViewListCell, MyStruct> {
    UICollectionView.CellRegistration<MyCollectionViewListCell, MyStruct>(
        cellNib: MyCollectionViewListCell.nib(MyCollectionViewListCell.self)
    ) { cell, indexPath, headerItem in
        let headerDisclosureOption = UICellAccessory.OutlineDisclosureOptions(
            style: .header,
            tintColor: .systemGray)
            
        cell.accessories = [
            .outlineDisclosure(displayed: .whenNotEditing, options: headerDisclosureOption),
        ]
    }
}
```

`MyCollectionViewListCell` is a subclass of `UICollectionViewListCell`.
`UICellAccessory.OutlineDisclosureOptions` doesn't have any options to configure such fields. What are my options in this case?